# Structure fields contain the information of next fields

Tags: c

I'm new to working with files in C...just started this week. I would appreciate your help...

I'm working with files and structures in C. Running the program, I ask for information to fill in several fields.

here is the content of the file:

```
111 12 2 2022 12 0 13 2 2022 14 0 opolisttt listtt ttt
```

The correct should be:

```
111 12 2 2022 12 0 13 2 2022 14 0 opo lis ttt
```

For sure I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what... Any help?

Comment: A C string requires a terminating null. Add 1 to all your character array: `char numerovoo[11];`, ...

Comment: You must check the value returned by `scanf` rather than just assuming it writes anything meaningful into your variables.  eg, if you try to read using `"%d"` and the next character in the input stream is not a digit, then `scanf` will not read any data, will not assign a value to the associated variable, and will return 0.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You got it.... Problem solved... Now  I notice that this problem just happens when I use the complete length of the array: I used the 3 characters of the airport code, so, no space for the null.... Thanks a lot... You saved my day...:)

Comment: Please create an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: as @SergeBallesta wrote, I had to add 1 to all character arrays. I just had troubles when I used the full length of the array, then, no space for the null terminator.